# Sql Query to Compare Same Field having differnet values because of Group Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have Query where I need to compare a amount field which has grouped by debit credit, I want to get the out put where the amount of credit is not equal to amount of debit the query is

```
select t_vocno,
       sum(t_amt),
       dc_type 
from   accotran 
where  f_yr = '1718' 
and    comp_cd = 'skl' 
group by  t_vocno, 
          dc_type 
order by t_vocno
```

which gives output

```
1   215452.1600 D
1   215452.1600 C
2   207586.0000 D
2   207586.0000 C
3   248789.0000 D
3   248789.0000 C
```

I have very bid data so I want to put a having condition and get the data where debit <> credit

I have tried

```
select t_vocno,
       sum(t_amt),
       dc_type 
from   accotran 
where  f_yr = '1718' 
and    comp_cd = 'skl' 
group by t_vocno,
         dc_type 
having case when dc_type= 'c' and t_vocno = t_vocno then sum(t_amt) end <>
       case when dc_type= 'd' and t_vocno = t_vocno then sum(t_amt)  end
order by t_vocno
```

Comment: Can you include create table with inserts?

Comment: @scar80 it is pretty big table with too big data, I can show you the screen shot if u want

Comment: do you need `dc_type` in the result ?

Comment: @Squirrel for the problem I had today it wasn't necessary but if I can get the answer for that, that will be useful in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` just `t_vocno` and use *conditional aggregation* to calculate credit / debit sums:

```
select t_vocno,
       sum(case when dc_type= 'c' then t_amt else 0 end) as c_sum,
       sum(case when dc_type= 'd' then t_amt else 0 end) as d_sum
from   accotran 
where  f_yr = '1718' 
and    comp_cd = 'skl' 
group by t_vocno
having sum(case when dc_type= 'c' then t_amt else 0 end) <>
       sum(case when dc_type= 'd' then t_amt else 0 end)
order by t_vocno
```

Comment: for the query u have written, can we group it on dc_type which is debit or credit

Comment: @ManojPatil If you group by `dc_type` then you won't be able to compare the partial sums, `c_sum` and `d_sum`, to each other.

Comment: Yeah, i'm checking it.. the main thing I want is not equal debit creidts.. that's all

Comment: @ Giorgos Betsos Thanks a Lot